# Issues with the authenticate() action in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.0 with Xampp 3.2.1 and I get an error message "Aplication error" , I've found out where the problem lies  as you can see in the snippet :

```
public function loginAction() {

    $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();
    $this->view->form = $form;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $data = $form->getValues();
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($users->getAdapter(), 'users');
            $authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('username')->setCredential('password');
            $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['username'])->setCredential($data['password']);

            $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter); // <- The problem is here
            $dump = $result->getCode();
            var_dump($dump);
            die;

            if ($result->isValid()) {
                $storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
                $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject());
                $this->_redirect('Authentification/login');
            } else {
                $this->view->errorMessage = "Invalid username or password!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Zend and can't really figure out how to solve this, are there better ways to solve this than `var_dump`? I've tried xdebug but can't manage to make it work for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to turn on display errors through config/application.ini

Check for this three lines must be set to 1 in [production] and [development : production] stages:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

So you get the proper errors messages regarding exceptions or any other errors.